# Why is SteamCMD failing to download Steam client updates anonymously in my Docker image build?

Tags: docker, steam

I'm running into an issue when trying to update the Steam client using SteamCMD. Here's the `RUN` command in my Dockerfile:

```
# Update Steam using SteamCMD.
RUN sudo mkdir -p /steam && \
    /usr/games/steamcmd +force_install_dir /steam +login anonymous +app_update 90 validate +quit
```

The download seems to go fine but the validation is throwing this error:

```
56.10 Loading Steam API...OK
56.28
56.28 Connecting anonymously to Steam Public...OK
57.97 Waiting for client config...OK
57.97 Waiting for user info...OK
65.96  Update state (0x3) reconfiguring, progress: 0.00 (0 / 0)
65.96  Update state (0x61) downloading, progress: 0.00 (0 / 110377440)
65.96  Update state (0x61) downloading, progress: 52.16 (57567668 / 110377440)
65.96 Error! App '90' state is 0x10E after update job.
```

Google seems to indicate that logging in anonymously might be the issue but I don't think that makes much sense for updating the public client. Other workarounds I've found like `+app_set_config 90 mod czero` have not worked. Anyone have any idea what I might be able to do here?